# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! , This error i am getting

Tags: go, goroutine

I am receiving this error in function `FindPathConcurently` . Since i am new to Go i am trying to make a sense out of it but unable to any help would really be appreciated. I am trying to resolve a problem where i am writing code for maze solver. Node is just a struct with next and value.

```golang
func FindExitConcurrently(root []*Node, paths chan []string, path []string, index int) {
    for _, node := range root {
        if node.Value == consts.SUCCESS {
            paths <- path
            return
        }
        if node.Next == nil {
            path = nil
            return
        }
        path = append(path, node.Value)
        index++
        FindExitConcurrently(node.Next, paths, path, index)
        path = nil
        index--
    }
    if index == 0 {
        close(paths)
    }
}

func FindPathConcurrently(parentNode *Node) {
    var pathChannels []chan []string
    for key, value := range parentNode.Next {
        pathChannels = append(pathChannels, make(chan []string))
        go FindExitConcurrently(value.Next, pathChannels[key], nil, 0)
    }
    cases := make([]reflect.SelectCase, len(pathChannels))
    for i, ch := range pathChannels {
        cases[i] = reflect.SelectCase{Dir: reflect.SelectRecv, Chan: reflect.ValueOf(ch)}
    }

    remaining := len(cases)
    for remaining > 0 {
        chosen, value, ok := reflect.Select(cases)
        if !ok {
            // The chosen channel has been closed, so zero out the channel to disable the case
            cases[chosen].Chan = reflect.ValueOf(nil)
            remaining -= 1
            continue
        }
        //fmt.Printf("Read from channel %#v and received %s\n", pathChannels[chosen], value.String())
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a deadlock by not closing the channels consistently. Consider *all* the paths that lead out of your goroutines (hint: some of them `return` early and thus skip the `close(...)` call).

To solve concurrency issues, use your favorite IDE with a Go debugger. VSCode with the Go extension works great - just start a debug session, and it will automatically break on a `panic`. Then you can inspect the "call stack" window to see where each goroutine is actually at.

But the main problem is the code is unnecessarily complex. You just need one channel really.

Something like this should be more readable, and thus less error-prone:

```
func FindExits(root []*Node, paths chan []string, path []string) {
    for _, node := range root {
        if node.Value == consts.SUCCESS {
            paths <- path
            return
        }
        FindExits(node.Next, paths, append(path, node.Value))
        if path != nil {
            path = append([]string{}, path...) // detach the slice
        }
    }
}

func FindExitConcurrently(root []*Node, paths chan []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    FindExits(root, paths, nil)
    wg.Done()
}

func FindPathConcurrently(parentNode *Node) {
    pathCh := make(chan []string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, next := range parentNode.Next {
        wg.Add(1)
        go FindExitConcurrently(next.Next, pathCh, &wg)
    }
    go func() {
        for value := range pathCh {
            fmt.Println(strings.Join(value, ","))
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(pathCh)
}
```